# How to find all resourcepools in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way to find all resourcepools in the main agent? E.g. I have created different resourcepools like operator, equipment, storage, etc. And i want to store all of them in a collection. But instead of manually adding them to the collection, can i search through the entire main agent for all the resourcepools and directly add them to the collection using Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Loop through objects and check if they are resource pools. If you are on `Main`, you can call this code, it checks all objects on Main (or where ever you call it from):

```
for (Object currentObject : getObjects(){
    if (currentObject instanceof ResourcePool) {
        // add here
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, i tried and i think getObjects() doesn't work, but getEmbeddedObjects works :D thanks for your help!

for (Object currentObject : getEmbeddedObjects()){
    if (currentObject instanceof ResourcePool) {
        col_Process.add(currentObject);
    }
}

Comment: Fair, it was from the top of my head